# Updating records in Formview when no ObjectDataSource is used

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a formview that is NOT using a `ObjectDataSource` in the aspx markup but rather a `DataTable` like this:

```
Member_Information memInfo = new Member_Information();
Guid _memberId = Guid.Empty;
_memberId = new Guid(lboxNewUsers.SelectedValue);
System.Data.DataTable dt = memInfo.MemberInfoById(_memberId);

fvReviewMemberDetail.DataSource = dt;
fvReviewMemberDetail.DataBind();
```

What is the best way to fetch the data from the controls within the formview? I thought perhaps `fvReviewMemberDetail.FindControl("mytextbox")` but how do you differentiate controls between `<ItemTemplate>` and `<EditItemTemplate>` templates. Obviously fornview would be in edit mode but the controls have same id across the two templates.

I have to noe that I've searched google but a string such as `not using ObjectDataSource` doesn't understand the NOT part.

Comment: Why would you need controls in read only template rather than having labels or just static texts?

Comment: You're absolutelly right, it was an oversight while trying to put things in to writing. So no I wouldn't.

Comment: Which templates are problematic then? Inserttemplate and edittemplate?

Comment: It's the edit template.

Comment: Edit template and ... ? You mention TWO templates you have to differentiate controls between.